# Expand a div's width dynamically to content once div height has reached the max-height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a class of `div`s that I need to dynamically change the width of in case the `div` grows beyond the `height` of the `max-height` of `120px`. The reason it needs to grow dynamically is that I'm `append`ing text content to the `div` and sometimes there is too much text to fit.

Right now, the div appears as follows: 
**HTML**

```
<div class="arrow_box"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.arrow_box{
  width:320px;
  max-height:120px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var timelineSentences = ["OjVIQgtdei NFrqcgRKpy orPfulDVcs eisVloPqXC wfSFifDQqK ghPZyeNKJE wryCLNvlQp pOErunxEtg FyZlcZxkhl xfNSVRuymx HxKxiRTYza AnyUKcgKNO gsYuTscCvx VjIphTkFSc LxmDDASiuI HbWLNJpsVC tTtmBMJsHd asXCGlFqxS vBGpsVkgtN gCPTSKWzog dsAZwIwPbC pWZanKGAFZ dielrXJNMb LZqwCdRtIT viqdgYHGfp PUxhrwKfkG MaiiJUYFOo cfAXxiHTNB TxOqTtxvmg gzmKznNrJF"]

$('.arrow_box').append('<p  style="margin-bottom:0;padding:10px;">'+timelineSentences[0]+'</p>');
```

I saw a couple of related posts [A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296793/change-a-divs-height-to-auto-using-jquery-once-the-div-reaches-a-certain-height) [B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149412/make-content-force-div-grow-vertically-until-max-height-is-reached-and-then-gro) but couldn't derive an answer from them after a number of attempts to adjust the `scrollHeight`

Comment: how are you appending the new content? that code is good context for this question

Comment: @maudulus I have written a Pure JavaScript solution below with 2 approaches. Have a look. Thanks!

Comment: @maudulus I have also written a jQuery solution below with both the approaches. Have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the code below. It works based on the `scrollHeight`.

**Pure `JavaScript` solution**

**Sample `<div>`**

```
<div class="arrow_box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

> **Approach 1** - If `scrollHeight` is greater than `maxHeight`, make `<div> 100%`
>
> ```
> <script>
>   var
>     arrowBox = document.querySelector('.arrow_box'),  // Get element
>     scrollHeight = arrowBox.scrollHeight,  // Get scrollHeight
>     maxHeight = 120;
>
>   if (scrollHeight > maxHeight) {
>     // Make width as 100%
>     arrowBox.style.width = '100%';
>   }
> </script>
> ```
>
> **Approach 2** - Increase width equivalent to the exceeded height in `pixels`
>
> ```
> <script>
>   var
>     arrowBox = document.querySelector('.arrow_box'),  // Get element
>     scrollHeight = arrowBox.scrollHeight,  // Get scrollHeight
>     maxHeight = 120,
>     constantFactor = 3;  // To make sure after readjusting the width, content does not overflow again
>
>   if (scrollHeight > maxHeight) {
>     // Increase width equivalent to the exceeded height in pixels
>     var extraPx = (scrollHeight - maxHeight) * constantFactor;
>     arrowBox.style.width = (arrowBox.offsetWidth + extraPx) + 'px';
>   }
> </script>
> ```

**`jQuery` solution** with both the approach!

```
(document).ready(function() {
  var timelineSentences = ["OjVIQgtdei NFrqcgRKpy orPfulDVcs eisVloPqXC wfSFifDQqK ghPZyeNKJE wryCLNvlQp pOErunxEtg FyZlcZxkhl xfNSVRuymx HxKxiRTYza AnyUKcgKNO gsYuTscCvx VjIphTkFSc LxmDDASiuI HbWLNJpsVC tTtmBMJsHd asXCGlFqxS vBGpsVkgtN gCPTSKWzog dsAZwIwPbC pWZanKGAFZ dielrXJNMb LZqwCdRtIT viqdgYHGfp PUxhrwKfkG MaiiJUYFOo cfAXxiHTNB TxOqTtxvmg gzmKznNrJF"]

  $('.arrow_box').append('<p style="margin-bottom: 0; padding: 10px;">' + timelineSentences[0] + '</p>');

  // ...
  // CODE BELOW
  // ...
```

> **Approach 1** - If `scrollHeight` is greater than `maxHeight`, make `<div> 100%`
>
> ```
>   var
>     arrowBox = $('.arrow_box'),  // Get element
>     scrollHeight = arrowBox.prop('scrollHeight'),  // Get scrollHeight
>     maxHeight = 120;
>
>   if (scrollHeight > maxHeight) {
>     // Make width as 100%
>     arrowBox.width('100%');
>   }
> });  // Close ready() function
> ```
>
> **Approach 2** - Increase width equivalent to the exceeded height in `pixels`
>
> ```
>   var
>     arrowBox = $('.arrow_box'),  // Get element
>     scrollHeight = arrowBox.prop('scrollHeight'),  // Get scrollHeight
>     maxHeight = 120,
>     constantFactor = 3;  // To make sure after readjusting the width, content does not overflow again
>
>   if (scrollHeight > maxHeight) {
>     // Increase width equivalent to the exceeded height in pixels
>     var extraPx = (scrollHeight - maxHeight) * constantFactor;
>     arrowBox.width((arrowBox.width() + extraPx) + 'px');
>   }
> });  // Close ready() function
> ```

Hope it helps!